# How to count the number of occurences of urls and hyperlinks in a Ruby string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, algorithm, blogs

Say a user submits this comment on a blog:

> @SO - Great community, but we've also
>   seen some great communities at [Stack
>   Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). At the same time
>   Google's Gmail (http://gmail.com) is a
>   great example of a community with
>   endless bounds. I'm just wondering if
>   anyone will really go toe-to-toe with
>   something like http://www.twitter.com.
>   What do you think?

**Note:** the 3rd url was actually posted as plain text, but SO converted it to a hyperlink.

Anyways, the total url and hyperlink count should be 3.

So, from a Ruby and/or Ruby on Rails perspective:
**How to count the number of occurences of urls and hyperlinks in a Ruby string?**

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy, albeit relatively naive:

```
string.count("http://")
```

Of course, it won't pick up links without a leading "http://", but that might be a reasonable assumption.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, but you are correct in that your method is a bit naive. What about the "https://" case? Or a plain "www.*" case?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to scan for "http" pattern, but really it can be more complicated, because sometimes urls haven't got "http://" at the beggining

```
string = "@SO - Great community, but we've also seen some great communities at <a href='http://blabla'>Stack Overflow</a>. At the same time Google's Gmail (http://gmail.com) is a great example of a community with endless bounds. I'm just wondering if anyone will really go toe-to-toe with something like http://www.twitter.com. What do you think?"
string.scan(/http/).size #=> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions is a good way. Here is an example on how to do that:

```
yourpost.each do |yourword|
     if yourword =~ /^(((ht|f)tps?\:\/\/)|~/|/)?([a-zA-Z]{1}([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,5})(:[\d]{1,5})?)/?(\w+\.[\w]{3,4})?((\?\w+=\w+)?(&\w+=\w+)*)?/
            puts %Q!We found #{$&} an URL in #{$1}!
    end
end
```

See [this](http://flanders.co.nz/2009/11/08/a-good-url-regular-expression-repost/) post for further discussion on regular expressions matching URLs.

Comment: mmmm... not sure. check out the link. it has a lot of discussion on URL searching with regexps.